# Getting Null Pointer Exception in MediaPlayer in Android?

Tags: android, media-player, uri, ringtone

I am working to play RINGTONES pragmatically in MEDIA PLAYER. Prior to this, I have **stored all my RINGTONES absolute path in SQLite DB**. At the time when I have to play the ringtone, I need to fetch the path from DB and convert it to URI and Play the ringtones but I am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION in line 2 of below code.

```
    Uri u = Uri.parse(soundpath);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, u);
    Context con  =getApplicationContext();
    player.setWakeMode(con,PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
    player.start();
```

On debug, I get the value of variable **soundpath** as **/content:/media/internal/audio/media/23**

Please suggest me.

**EDITED**: Code used to store all the Ringtones in HASHMAP

```
 Ringtone ringtone = ringtoneMgr.getRingtone(currentPosition);
                System.out.println(ringtone.getTitle(this));
                File uripath=new File(ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(currentPosition).toString());
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ringtonemap.put(ringtone.getTitle(this), uripath.getAbsolutePath());
                arraylist.add(ringtone.getTitle(this));
```

Comment: That uri doesn't look right. It should be `content://media/internal/audio/media/23` - are you storing it correctly?

Comment: I am getting 'content:/media/internal/audio/media/23' as URI and converting it to absolute path and save it to hashmap.

Comment: Even the wrong uri shouldn't cause null pointer exception in line 2. So I'm not sure what's going on. Please post the stacktrace and ideally more of the mediaplayer creation code (what context is it in, etc.)?

Comment: I think you are right, I have copy paste your specified URI and it is working now.

Comment: I have added my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That uri doesn't look right. It should be `content://media/internal/audio/media/23` - are you storing it correctly?

Make sure you are storing them correctly. If it's not possible the change how they are stored, you can always format them correctly before passing to the `MediaPlayer`

```
soundpath = soundpath.replaceAll("/content:/", "content://");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was converting the URI path from String to File, which was not required. 
The mistake was at the path generation time.
New code is posted below:

```
Ringtone ringtone = ringtoneMgr.getRingtone(currentPosition);
            System.out.println(ringtone.getTitle(this));
        String  uri =ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(currentPosition).toString();
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ringtonemap.put(ringtone.getTitle(this),uri);
            arraylist.add(ringtone.getTitle(this));
```

At the time when I have to play the ringtone:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(soundpath));
```